# Select all html elements except ones with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code puts all html elements with a class of 'a' into an array called 'items'.

```
var items = $('.a').get();
```

What would I have to write to do the opposite? By that I mean, put all html elements EXCEPT .a into an array?

The code below, and several variations, didn't work.

```
var items = !$('.a').get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body *:not(.a)')
```

or:

```
$('body *').not('.a')
```

If you need to include the stuff in `<head></head>` as well, just remove the body from the selector.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a tiny tweak. You missed out the class selector on the 'a'. 

    (Should be $('body *').not('.a') and $('body *:not(.a)')

Comment: This will exclude all a element not only element with class `a`

Comment: Sorry about that, misread that. I figured you wanted everything but links for some reason.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. Using 'a' as a class was probably a bad example!

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = $(':not(.a)').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
$('*').not('.a')
```